# EF Core query is not translated to t-sql the way I expected it

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, where-clause, row-number

I have two entities, defined:

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MemberHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; } = default!;
    public string CT1 { get; set; } = default!;
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository I'm creating this query:

```
var maxDate = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);
var result = context.MemberHistories
    .Where(x => x.CreatedAt.Date <= maxDate.Date)
    .GroupBy(x => x.MemberId)
    .Select(x => x
        .OrderByDescending(mh => mh.CreatedAt)
        .First())
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like("CT1", "%1"))
    .ToList();

return result;
```

This gets translated to (except for the dates, I copied actual dates iso a variable):

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[CT1], [t0].[CreatedAt], [t0].[MemberId]
      FROM (
          SELECT [m].[MemberId]
          FROM [MemberHistories] AS [m]
          WHERE CONVERT(date, [m].[CreatedAt]) <= '2022-01-01'
          GROUP BY [m].[MemberId]
          HAVING N'CT1' LIKE N'%1'
      ) AS [t]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[CT1], [t1].[CreatedAt], [t1].[MemberId]
          FROM (
              SELECT [m0].[Id], [m0].[CT1], [m0].[CreatedAt], [m0].[MemberId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [m0].[MemberId] ORDER BY [m0].[CreatedAt] DESC) AS [row]
              FROM [MemberHistories] AS [m0]
              WHERE CONVERT(date, [m0].[CreatedAt]) <= '2022-01-01'
          ) AS [t1]
          WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1
      ) AS [t0] ON [t].[MemberId] = [t0].[MemberId]
```

I expected the result to be:

- Per 'MemberId', the latest record on or before 'maxDate' (this seems to be fine)
- This result should then be filtered to only contain those records where 'CT1' ends in '1'

But it gives me the latest records (before date) per memberId where there is a record in the database (before date) for said memberId with 'CT1' equals to '%1'.

In my mind, the translated t-sql is wrong.
The line

```
HAVING N'CT1' LIKE N'%1'
```

is in the wrong place.

It should be something like (no 'HAVING' and an extra where clause on the resulting dataset):

```
SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[CT1], [t0].[CreatedAt], [t0].[MemberId]
      FROM (
          SELECT [m].[MemberId]
          FROM [MemberHistories] AS [m]
          GROUP BY [m].[MemberId]
      ) AS [t]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[CT1], [t1].[CreatedAt], [t1].[MemberId]
          FROM (
              SELECT [m0].[Id], [m0].[CT1], [m0].[CreatedAt], [m0].[MemberId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [m0].[MemberId] ORDER BY [m0].[CreatedAt] DESC) AS [row]
              FROM [MemberHistories] AS [m0]
              WHERE CONVERT(date, [m0].[CreatedAt]) <= '2022-01-01'
          ) AS [t1]
          WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1
  ) AS [t0] ON [t].[MemberId] = [t0].[MemberId] ) AS RESULT
WHERE [CT1] LIKE '%1'
```

or even shorter (because I don't see why this query should include the join, but this has probably to do with EF's inner workings):

```
SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[CT1], [t1].[CreatedAt], [t1].[MemberId]
  FROM (
      SELECT [m0].[Id], [m0].[CT1], [m0].[CreatedAt], [m0].[MemberId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [m0].[MemberId] ORDER BY [m0].[CreatedAt] DESC) AS [row]
  FROM [MemberHistories] AS [m0]
    WHERE CONVERT(date, [m0].[CreatedAt]) <= '2022-01-01'
  ) AS [t1]
  WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1 AND [CT1] LIKE '%1'
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

PS: I also tried replacing the line

```
.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like("CT1", "%1"))
```

with

```
.Where(x => x.CT1.EndsWith("1"))
```

But that did not work either, because the I get a '"The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary."' exception.

Comment: I wanted to suggest a change in the code. Instead of using `.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like("CT1", "%1"))`, we could use `.Where(x => x.CT1.EndsWith("1"))`. This would filter the results to only include records where the `CT1` property ends with the character `"1"`.  @Hiver

Comment: After grouping the results by `MemberId` using `.GroupBy(x => x.MemberId)`, we could add a `.Where(x => x.CT1.EndsWith("1"))` clause.

Comment: I tried using 'EndsWith': see the PS in my original post.
Adding the suggested where clause directly after the GroupBy would not work, because the 'x' is of type IGrouping. Plus: this is not what I want. I need the last case (before a certain date) per memberId. The filter should only be applied to the result. What @Laaziv is suggesting would alter the result of the GroupBy/Select (which is not bad per se, but not what I need at the moment)

Comment: .Where(x => x.CreatedAt.Date <= maxDate.Date && x.CT1.EndsWith("1") )

Comment: Thanks for the reply laaziv, but that doesn’t do it either. If you put this directly on the MemberHistory, you’re already filtering on CT1.  This I don’t want. What I need is the situation on a certain date (per MemberId) and once you have this situation, check if the member’s CT1 ends with 1. What you’re suggesting would give me the latest situation where the member has a CT1 that ends with 1. This is not exactly my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that might solve your problem:

```cs
var subquery1 = _context.Set<Entity.MemberHistory>()
                .Where(m => m.CreatedAt <= maxDate)
                .GroupBy(m => m.MemberId)
                .Select(g => new { MemberId = g.Key, CreatedAt = g.Max(m => m.CreatedAt) });

var result2 = _context.Set<Entity.MemberHistory>()
                .Join(subquery,
                    m => new { m.MemberId, m.CreatedAt },
                    s => new { s.MemberId, s.CreatedAt },
                    (m, s) => m)
                .Where(m => m.CT1.EndsWith("1"))
                .ToList();
```

The generated SQL query should look like this:

```sql
SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[CT1], [m].[CreatedAt], [m].[MemberId]
      FROM [MemberHistory] AS [m]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [m0].[MemberId], MAX([m0].[CreatedAt]) AS [CreatedAt]
          FROM [MemberHistory] AS [m0]
          WHERE [m0].[CreatedAt] <= @__maxDate_0
          GROUP BY [m0].[MemberId]
      ) AS [t] ON [m].[MemberId] = [t].[MemberId] AND [m].[CreatedAt] = [t].[CreatedAt]
      WHERE [m].[CT1] LIKE N'%1'
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem. Please let me know if you need any further assistance.